Sharepoint list disable ALL edit
is there a way to disable all edit methods in a sharepoint list?
I have a Powerautomate workflow that saves data in a sharepoint list. As i do not want users to tamper with the data in the list, i'm looking for a configuration/setting that prevents users from editing the list. The list should be read-only to any human. The only way to update the list, in my head, is throught the workflow.
Searching the web i could only find how to prevent editing in grid view, but this way the list can still be modified if i select an item and click Edit button.
